# Making an API accessible throughout all widgets - use Provider with already instantiated variable?

Tags: flutter, global, flutter-provider

I wrote an API class that, obviously, encapsulates a couple http requests. However, this API class also stores a little bit of state: Namely, it saves an authentication token that will be used in all subsequent requests after the first.

In my flutter function, I then first wait for that token to be set before doing anything else:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  var api = MyAPI();
  await api.auth.refreshTokens(); // Sets api.auth.token
  runApp(MaterialApp(etc));
```

What is important here is that in `etc` I am also setting Providers, one of which being that very API:

```
providers: [Provider(create: (context) => api), ...]
```

which I then want to use all throughout my app. However, is that really the best way to go about it? It seems like a really really cumbersome and messy approach to simply be able to use this more or less global API object.

How is it usually done?

Answer (score 0):

You can write that class as a singleton, this way you can call the constructor and obtaining each time the same instance without creating a new one:

```dart
void main() {
  Api().call();
  Api().call();
}

class Api {
  static Api? _instance;

  Api._();
  factory Api() {
    _instance ??= Api._();
    return _instance!;
  }

  String token = '';

  void call() {
    token += '*';
    print('new token $token');
  }
}
```

Comment: And that state is persistent? If so, why the need for the whole Provider... stuff in Flutter? It seems like it just overly complexifies things

Comment: They are different patterns. The singleton is persistent, but doesn't notify its update and is available code wide. While provider is available only to a subset of the widget tree. Provider is also influenced by changes in the application context (you need one in order to use it) while a singleton is just a lower level pattern that guarantees you to have one and only instance of a class for all the lifetime of your app